# Android carat/cursor for hints

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I notice that if I use android:hint and centralize my hint with android:gravity="center", this will lead to the carat being centralized when the EditText receives focus.

Out of curiousity, does anyone know if it is possible to still have carat at start of hint, when hint is centralized?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious way to do what you asked.

Have you considered making the caret invisible at first, then making it visible + removing the hint when the user activates it via event handlers?

Comment: I was contemplating different ways of achieving the above behavior (text centralized, caret not centralized but positioned at start of text), but when I realize that caret positioning does not treat hint as per normal text (Selection.setSelection does not work on hints it seems) I dropped the idea of centralizing my hint. Setting android:gravity="center" adds to some complication with android:inputType anyway if I'm using android:hint, and since the default google apps all uses hints to the left, guess I'll just leave it as that =)